# Trouble retrieving gRPC error details in gRPC-web client

Tags: javascript, grpc, grpc-web

I'm working on a project that uses gRPC-web for communication between the client (written in JavaScript) and the server. I'm having difficulties retrieving error details from the gRPC response on the client side.

Could someone guide me on the correct approach or library for retrieving error details from a gRPC response in a gRPC-web client, specifically when using the grpc-web-client library?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

What I Tried:
I attempted to retrieve error details from gRPC metadata in my gRPC-web client. The error details are present in the metadata as a string. Here's a simplified version of my client code:

```
const detailsBase64 = error.metadata['grpc-status-details-bin'];
const detailsBinary = atob(detailsBase64);
const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(detailsBinary.length);
for (let i = 0; i < detailsBinary.length; ++i) {
  uint8Array[i] = detailsBinary.charCodeAt(i);
}
const myProto = MyProto.deserializeBinary(uint8Array);
```

What I Expected:
I expected that by accessing the metadata, I would be able to retrieve the error details.

What Actually Resulted:
When attempting to access the metadata and retrieve the error details, I encountered issues during deserialization. The error details retrieved from the metadata as a string could not be deserialized properly, resulting in an error. The specific error message or type of deserialization issue is `Error: Assertion failed`.

The error data is an object containing extra information about the error, some thing like the below, but can be anything:

```
{
  value: 'AB123',
  field: 'REM',
  detail: 'Wrong format',
}
```

Comment: Less familiar with gRPC-Web but have a look at this [Decoding `grpc-status-details-bin`](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/issues/399) and specifically [this](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/issues/399#issuecomment-658259826) solution.

Comment: Thanks for posting the question! While i'm not exactly familiar with the issue, i wonder if you can take a look at the pointer DazWilkin provided above? And also, some users have reported ways how they made it work [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/issues/399#issuecomment-838168167); could you look at them as well? thanks!